# What is the relation between this subgroup and its conjugates?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

Let $S$ be an infinite set, and let $A(S)$ denote the group of all bijections of $S$ onto itself. Let $M \subset A(S)$ be the set of all elements $f \in A(S)$ such that $f(s) \neq s$ for at most a finite number of elements $s \in S$. Then $M$ is a subgroup of $A(S)$.

Now let $g$ be a given element of $A(S)$. What is the relation between $M$ and its conjugate subgroup by $g$, viz. the subgroup 
$$g^{-1} M g := \{ g^{-1}fg | f \in M \}?$$ 
Can we establish that $M = g^{-1} M g$?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. For if $f(s)=s$ and $t$ is such that $g(t)=s$ then $g^{-1}fg(t)=t$ and conversely. So $g$ gives a bijection between fixed points for $f$ and $g^{-1}fg$.